# Mutate: assign multiple variables at once

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a function which looks like the following (simplified)

```
get_identifiers<-function(shares){
  result<-c()
  for(share in shares){
    
    result<-rbind(result,c("2", "2"))
  }
  return (result)
}
```

It returns two columns!

Now, I would like to call that function and assign its values to two variables of my existing tibble. I am looking for something like

```
res %>% mutate(vars(c("identifier","sedol")),get_identifiers(symbol))
```

How can I achieve that?

I know that I could do something like the following which seems not to be very efficient

```
res %>% mutate(identifier=get_identifiers(symbol)[1]) 
  %>% mutate(sedol=get_identifiers(symbol)[2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make few changes in the function -

```
get_identifiers<-function(shares){
  result<-c()
  for(share in shares){
    result<- rbind(result,c("2", "2"))
  }
  result <- data.frame(result)
  names(result) <- c("identifier","sedol")
  return (result)
}
```

(*There are better ways to write the above code but I understand that this is just a simplified example.*)

and then save the output in a list and use `unnest_wider` to get them in different columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res %>% 
  mutate(data = list(get_identifiers(symbol))) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)
```